# MySQL query to update multiple rows based on a column using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Is there a way that I could update several rows based on a column?

I have a table called category with 2 columns (Category, number).
The column category have 2 rows(Agriculture,Apparel) which is fixed. I need a mySQL update statement that could update the number column. That means 2 rows in 'number' column will have to be updated.

The code that I gave could only update one row at the time. How do I update both rows using a single query? Thanks.

My code:

```
$sql="UPDATE category
    SET number = '$AF'
    WHERE Category = 'Agriculture' ";
```

Comment: The query that you have now will update more than one row if you have multiple rows where Category = Agriculture. Perhaps you could setup a SQL fiddle to illustrate your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure I'm understanding. If you want to update all of the rows, then remove your `where` clause. SQL is very much a "the less you put in the query, the more you get"-type language.

If you want to change the values of the `number` field to DIFFERENT values, but in a single query, then you have to do a very ugly:

```
UPDATE category
SET number = CASE Category
   WHEN 'Agriculture' THEN $value_for_agriculture
   WHEN 'Apparel' THEN $value_for_apparel
END CASE
```